# Choose specific sqlite database and create table in it

Tags: java, database

there is some thing that i found no real answer after searching alot about it, the question is in android when you create more than 1 sqlite database, can you call a specific database to open with or without `getWritabledatabase()` . and then i tried alot to call this code :

```
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 SingleChatDataSource datasource;

 datasource = new SingleChatDataSource(this);
 datasource.open();
final String TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TOURS + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_IMAGE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_PRICE + " NUMERIC " +
        ")";


 db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
```

i get this error

```
05-25 23:27:00.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 23:27:00.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Process: com.example.xmppchattest, PID: 
05-25 23:27:00.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  
start service com.example.xmppchattest.WriterService@b2d4e430 with Intent { 
cmp=com.example.xmppchattest/.WriterService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2719)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

nullpointer exception is last thing i expected here, could some one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` is not initialized.

See [SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) on how to initialize `db` properly.

(There is also `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` a little further down on that page)